# how does Rails update associated models through other_model_ids?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have been using one of the standard techniques for creating/updating associated `has_many, through:` models by creating checkboxes and specifying the HTML element name to be a collection of ids. Consider:

```
<% Course.all.each do |course| %>
  <label class="checkbox">
    <%= check_box_tag 'student[course_ids][]', course.id, @student.course_ids.include?(course.id) %>
    <%= course.name %>
  </label>
```

To support this, the `Student` model has the following:

```
attr_accessible :course_ids, ...
has_many :student_courses, dependent: :destroy
has_many :courses, through: :student_courses
```

I have no problem with this, and it works great because the associated model, `StudentCourses`, gets created or deleted.

My question is how does Rails do the creation/deletion after I submit the form? I looked at the development log, and I see the Delete or Insert statements, but not the "magic" that Rails uses. More specifically, how does Rails use the `course_ids` param?

I looked into the code generated in the console (`rails c`), but they are similar to the dev log.

Thank you

Comment: I believe that Rails sets associated models the same way it would if you called `student.course_ids = [1,2,3]`, just as with other params. This method is generated by the `has_many :through` association, but the actual code for it is buried somewhere in ARel or ActiveRecord.

Comment: @MrTheWalrus Yes, thank you. How would you do it "manually"?

Comment: `@student.course_ids = params[:student][:course_ids]` in `StudentsController#update`? Not sure if I understand what you want to do.